# ClearCase MVFS files permissions

Tags: git, clearcase

I am starting to understand the issues I get during my repository synchronization between Git and ClearCase.

Let's take a look at this:

```
$ cd
$ touch foo && chmod 777 foo
$ ls -al foo
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 ch52198 Domain Users 0 Sep  4 15:04 foo
$ cd /vob/view/project/
$ cp ~/foo .
$ ls -al foo
$ -rw-r----- 1 ch52198 Domain Users 0 Sep  4 15:05 foo
$ chmod u+x foo
$ ls -al foo
$ -rw-r----- 1 ch52198 Domain Users 0 Sep  4 15:05 foo
```

ClearCase is doing everything wrong. It ignore all the files permissions when using a MVFS storage.

Things are getting worse because if on my local Git repository I set the executable flag on a script. I will never be able to keep this flag on my ClearCase repository.

How should I fix this issue?

I tried to use `cleartol protect -chmod 777 foo`, but I cannot see the permission change with Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the files you have copied, you would need a [`cleartool protect -chmod`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protect.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-2-1-24-3) to restore the permission.

Check also the `umask` you have in your view. That will determine how the mod associated to the file is set in a ClearCase view.

See also "[Access control for view-private files in dynamic views](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_access_view_private.htm)"

> On Linux and the UNIX system, the initial owner, group, and protection mode for a view-private file are determined by the following rules:
>
> - **Owner**. The initial owner is the user of the process that creates the file or directory.
> - **Group**. The initial group is the primary group of the process that creates the file or directory.
> - **Protection mode**. **The initial protection mode for a view-private file depends on the umask of the user who creates the file or directory. A umask is a setting supported on Linux and the UNIX system that specifies that some permissions are not granted when the user creates a file**. (For details, see the umask reference page on Linux or the UNIX system.)
>     When a user creates a view-private file or directory, Rational ClearCase begins with a set of permissions that depend on how the file or directory is created. The permissions specified by the user’s umask are then removed by Rational ClearCase.
>     For example, if the user’s umask is 002, write permission for others is removed by Rational ClearCase.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question. `ct protect -chmod` does not work as expected

Comment: @nowox What a `cleartool ls` or a `cleartool descr -l myFile` return? Are we talkins about a private file or a file added to source control?

Comment: cleartool ls returns a correct value. However my Cygwin bash cannot see the permissions

Comment: @nowox what is your umask in your Cygwin?

Comment: @nowox can you try with umask 002, just for testing?