# How can I commit permission changes?

Tags: permissions, commit, file-permissions, clearcase

I'm working on a ClearCase repository. Some of the files in it have, for some reason, execution permissions while they shouldn't (they're text files basically). I'll also mention I'm a user without root privilege.

If I check them out, change their permissions (the usual way, not with `ct permission -chmod`, which doesn't work), then try to check them back in - I'm told that:

```
ct: Error: By default, won't create version with data identical to predecessor.
```

How do I override this default? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding [`cleartool checkin`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fi/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkin.htm), the correct option would be:

```
-ide/ntical
```

(meaning `cleartool -ide` or `cleartool -identical`: short and long form of the `identical` option)

> Checks in the element even if the predecessor version is identical to the checked-out version.
>   By default, the checkin operation is canceled in such cases.

But in your case, this should not be needed: you do not need to checkin a `protect` change.

Try first a [`cleartool protect`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protect.htm) command (not `cleartool permission`)

```
cleartool protect -chmod 644 aFile
```

(provided [the restrictions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protect.htm#ref_protect_refsect1_4110905) allow the command to work, [with or without ACLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678073/6309))

Check also your [`umask` (for instance 002)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32399722/6309) used in your view (if you are on Unix)

Comment: Actually, the ONLY way to change the permissions after adding to source control is to use ct protect -chmod... Check out, followed by chmod and checkin isnt likely to work.

Comment: @BrianCowan I agree. I don't remember having to do any `co`/`ci` when I used `ct protect`.

Comment: `ide/ntical`? Typo with the slash?

Comment: @einpoklum No typo: it is the "IBM documentation" way to indicate the long and short form of an option `-ide` or `-identical`